# ADO equivalent for NZ function in MS Access?

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ado

I have the following command object:

```
ADODB::_CommandPtr pCmd("ADODB.Command");

pCmd->ActiveConnection = pConn;
pCmd->CommandType = ADODB::adCmdText;
pCmd->CommandText = L" select ID, NZ(PaymentAmount, 0) from Contracts;";

ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS = pCmd->Execute(NULL, NULL, ADODB::adCmdText);
```

When I run it, it reports error that [NZ](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c?CorrelationId=eaf74e37-17ec-45cb-98cb-230f63b4a4b3&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function does not exists.

Researching on my own, I have found out that I can not use `NZ` in ADO queries.

### QUESTION:

Is there ADO equivalent to this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `IIf` expression which produces the same result as `Nz`.

```sql
select ID, IIf(PaymentAmount Is Null, 0, PaymentAmount) As nz_PaymentAmount
from Contracts;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [IIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) together with [ISNULL](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/isnull.php) function.

```
select ID, IIf(ISNULL(PaymentAmount), 0, PaymentAmount) As nz_PaymentAmount
from Contracts;
```

Comment: I haveupvoted, but did not officially accept because he was first. Best regards.